# Java, adding arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, ide

i am working on a program to add numbers using an array. I have completed a lot of it but am troubled at the last part adding the actual numbers in the code. Here is my code.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter size of array");
    int n= input.nextInt();
    int[] x= new int[n];
    System.out.println("Enter Array nums");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        x[i]= input.nextInt(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? You code seems to be correct.

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: ***But am troubled at the last part*** ... that tells us so good as nothing... what exactly are you getting and what are you expecting....???

Comment: sorry, i have ordered everything but don't know how to actually add the nums

Comment: Use `+` operator or `+=` operator.

Comment: What exactly is the problem which you are facing? Is there some kind of Exception or what?

Comment: but would i need a for loop. but in which line?

Comment: @Altair I need to know how to add it

Comment: @J. Smith Your code is now reading number from the console and save it in an array of integers. I can't quite understand what you want to add. Do you want to add all the numbers which you typed from the console and get their sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just write some code to add numbers?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class X {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter size of array");
        int n= input.nextInt();
        int[] x= new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter Array nums");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            x[i]= input.nextInt();
        }
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            sum+= x[i];
        }
        // to print the result, uncomment the line below
        //System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you do `+=` in the first `for`?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Because There are no need of adding numbers other than 1 (in `i++`) in the first `for`.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Thank You very much. That was exactly what I couldn't understand how to do. Never realized how simple the code was, (I overthought it).            :)

Comment: `sum += (x[i] = input.nextInt())` looks prettier than yours

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Then, why do you need the array... because the question says "using an array"? Let's throw away `x` and just use `sum +=  input.nextInt();`

Comment: @MikeCAT, I'm not able to understand the advantage of using 2 loops here

Comment: @MikeCAT The reason why i need the array is because it is part of the requirement in the lesson.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to initial variable with 0 which will have a sum of all values and then while taking a input the values are added into the variable initialized for holding the total values in the same for loop.
Given below is the code for the same.

public static void main(String args[]){

```
     Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter size of array");
        int n= input.nextInt();
        int[] x= new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter Array nums");
        int total=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            x[i]= input.nextInt(); 
            total=total+x[i];
        }
        System.out.println("total"+total);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a method that will add up your array for you:

```
public int totalArray(int[] someArray) {
    int reply = 0;
    for (int value : someArray) reply += value;
    return reply;
}
```